Error: 429 Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota)
I get an error like this and it doesn't give it all the time. I stated as a prompt that it is a translation application, and while some translations are good, I get this error in others: Error: 429 Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota). I don't fully understand it, and sometimes it gives the following error: Error: Invalid operation: The response.text quick accessor requires the response to contain a valid Part, but none were returned. Please check the candidate.safety_ratings to determine if the response was blocked.
Also, if my quota is exhausted, why does the translation continue for some words?
def translate_text_gemini(text, source_lang, target_lang):
    # Boş veya NaN (pd.NA) durumunda metni döndür.
    if pd.isna(text) or text == '' or text == '**':
        return text
    
    try:
        # Modeli dışarda bir kere tanımlayıp tekrar kullanılabilir hale getirebilirsiniz.
        model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
        
        prompt = (f"Act like a language translation application. Translate the following text from {source_lang} to {target_lang}. Just write the translation equivalents, do not make any comments."
                  f"The text provided is purely for translation purposes and does not contain offensive or inappropriate content."
                  f"Make sure the translation is accurate and does not reflect any negative sentiments or inappropriate language."
                  f"Text: {text}")
                  
        # Çeviri isteği yapılıyor.
        response = model.generate_content(prompt)
        
        # Dönen yanıtı kontrol ediyoruz.
        if response and hasattr(response, 'text'):
            return response.text.strip()  # Strip ile gereksiz boşlukları kaldırıyoruz.
        else:
            return 'Translation failed or empty response'
    
    except Exception as e:
        # Hata durumunda hata mesajını döndürüyoruz.
        return f"Error: {str(e)}"

 
source_lang='tr'
target_lang='en'
existing_df['Gemini'] = existing_df['Türkçe-TR'].apply(lambda x: translate_text_gemini(x, source_lang, target_lang))
gd.set_with_dataframe(sheet, existing_df)


You're using the translate_text_gemini function to perform text translation with Gemini on a pandas dataframe. From a logical standpoint, your code appears to be sound. However, it's important to consider the technical limitations imposed by Gemini's user quota, particularly if your pandas dataframe contains a large number of records.
Unlike local function calls, Gemini AI (and other AI systems I'm aware of) takes time to generate responses, which can impact performance. Therefore, it's recommended to check your queries per second (QPS) limits and explore solutions such as threading or simple for-loops to address any potential issues.
Also check https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/quotas

yes that's exactly the problem

@SÜLEYMANYAŞAR - can you mark this answer as accepted? If so, we can close this request.

Also keep an eye on https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/multimodal/batch-prediction-gemini . If this feature become available, it might be helpful to you

Thank you very much

prompt = (
f"Act like a language translation application. Translate the following text from {source_lang} to "
f"{target_lang}. Just write the translation equivalents, do not make any comments. The text provided is "
f"purely for translation purposes and does not contain offensive or inappropriate content.Make sure the "
f"translation is accurate and does not reflect any negative sentiments or inappropriate language."
f"Text: {text}")
    response = model.generate_content(prompt, request_options=RequestOptions(
        retry=retry.Retry(initial=1, multiplier=1, maximum=60, timeout=10)))

    if response and hasattr(response, 'text'):
        return response.text.strip()

There was a situation related to the limits of API requests. It was necessary to set a limit for the request.
